# Derivative of Dirac delta function as a measure

Tags: measure-theory, distribution-theory

Dirac delta function can be defined in several ways. I know two definitions. One is as a distribution and the other is as a measure. I found many materials on the derivatives of delta function as a distribution. However, I couldn't find materials dealing derivatives of delta function as a measure. Could someone point me at any materials or explain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the sense of distributions, if $\phi$ is compactly supported and smooth in $\mathbb R^d$, $$\delta'(\phi)=-\delta(\phi')=-\phi'(0).$$ But, it is not possible to express this as a measure.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a proof of the last claim? Not doubting or saying you're wrong, just curious.

Comment: A proof can actually be found here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553585/about-the-derivative-of-dirac-delta-distribution .